# HTML - show event of today with a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I want my HTML page to show me the events/ in this case birthday(s) of this day. 
But my Code doesn't work.

```
  function birthday() {

var event = [];
var temp = [];

event[0] = ["31.10.1991", "test1"];
event[1] = ["11.12.2015", "TestToday"];

var datum = new Date();     
var today = today.getDate();    
var month = today.getMonth() + 1; 

for (i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
    if (event[i]) {
        if (event[i][0] == today && event[i][0] == month) {
            event[i][0] = temp[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}

if (temp.length == 0) {
    document.write("Today nobody has a birthday");
}
else {
    var x2 = "Today " + ((temp.length == 1) ? "has" : "have");
    for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        x2 += ((temp[i] > 0) ? ((temp[i] == (temp.length - 1)) ? " and " : ", ") : " ") + temp[event[1]][3] + "(" + temp[event[i]][2] + ")";
    }
    document.write(x2 + " birthday");
}
```

}

Question1: Where are my mistakes and how can I make it work?
Question2: How can the program take the dates out of a excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you define arrays using [];
I don't speak German so i don't know what you need to print

```
 function birthday() {

    var Geb = [];
    var ausgabe = [];

    Geb[0] = ["31.10.1991", "Test1"];
    Geb[1] = ["23.11.2000", "Testheute"];


    var datum = new Date();     //Datums Objekt
    var heute = datum.getDate();    //Tage 1-31
    var monat = datum.getMonth() + 1; //Monate von 0-11


    for (i = 0; i < Geb.length; i++) {
        if (Geb[i]) {
            if (Geb[i][0] == heute && Geb[i][0] == monat) {
                Geb[i][0] = ausgabe[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ausgabe.length == 0) {
        document.write("Heute hat niemand Geburtstag");
    }
    else {
        var x2 = "Heute " + ((ausgabe.length == 1) ? "hat" : "haben");
        for (i = 0; i < ausgabe.length; i++) {
            x2 += ((ausgabe[i] > 0) ? ((ausgabe[i] == (ausgabe.length - 1)) ? " und " : ", ") : " ") + ausgabe[Geb[i1]][3] + "(" + ausgabe[Geb[i]][2] + ")";
        }
        document.write(x2 + " Geburtstag");
    }

}

birthday();
```